# syntax of operator new[] while creating an array of pointers

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have problems while using `new[]` operator while creatin an array of pointers to `char`. Since `char*` is the type I want my elements to be of, I use parentheses to surround it, but it doesn't work:

```
char **p = new (char *)[vector.size()];
```

but when I get rid of parentheses it works:

```
char **p = new char *[vector.size()];
```

Why does the latter one work?

Comment: Why should it be right?!  You cannot use parentheses around types, e.g. `(int) x = 2;` is wrong.  The same is true for pointer types: `char* p = 0;` is right, `(char*) p = 0;` not.

Comment: because I think it should like this    int i; char *p = (char *)i;

Comment: Agree with @FerdinandBeyer, has "(int)a" the same meaning of "int a"?

Comment: Nothing to explain... you should use a `type` after the `new`. Here you are not doing that...

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just want to make it more easy to read, but finally made a mistake!

Comment: But you can do `char** p = new (char*[3]);` so the claims "you can't use parentheses around types" are not really 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of "declaration follows use". `char **p;` can be read as "if I dereference p twice, I will get a `char`". `(char*) *p` does not have a type on the left, and gets parsed as an expression meaning: "dereference `p` and cast the result to a pointer to `char`".

When `char **` gets used as a type name on its own, a similar convention holds. `(char*) *` does not parse as a type-name at all, but as an expression (because there is no type at the left).

Comment: You probably wanted to write "dereference `p` and cast the result to a pointer to `char`" :)

Comment: @LihO: Of course. Thanks. Feel free to fix such typos yourself in future (;

Answer (score 2):

`char *p = new char[10];` dynamically allocates a memory block for an array of size of 10 chars and returns the address of its first element which is then stored into `p` (making `p` to point to the beginning of this memory block).

In this case, the `new` keyword is followed by **an array type specifier**, you specify the **type**:
`char **p = new char*[10];` - type in this case is `char*`, not `(char*)`. Check [operator new[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/)

You are probably confused because of C-style `malloc` syntax where the type of its return value is always `void*`, which can be cast to different type so that you can dereference it. That's the situation where you use `(char*)` syntax (C-style type cast): `char *p = (char*) malloc(10);`
Although note that in C this cast is redundant: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1168156)

Note that memory that was allocated by using `new[]` should be freed by calling `delete[]` and memory allocated by `malloc` should be freed by `free`.